# Simple filter to change label name of Email Adress to something else

Tags: themes, forms, email, labels

i searched the whole internet without finding an adequate answer:

I simply want to change the label of the Email Adress from "Email-Adress:" to "Example"

i think this can be done by a simple add_filter in themes function.php right?

but i dont know how to exactly write it.
It should change the label name of email in general, meaning upon registration, in user profile, in woocommerce checkout etc. Instead of Email-Adress it should show Example (will change myself later)

Thanks so much for any tips

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'change_label_form' );
function change_label_form() {
  echo '<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("label[for=email]").html("Example");
  } );
  </script>';
}
```

here is trick worked for me , you can change the label for any filed by using the for tag in the label and you can add action on any form you like, as

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'change_label_form' );
```

Here is another trick you can use

```
add_action('admin_head-user-edit.php', 'setup_user_edit');

function setup_user_edit() {

  add_filter('gettext', 'change_profile_labels');
}

function change_profile_labels($input) {

if ('Email' == $input)
    return 'Example';

  return $input;
}
```

Comment: Which one of those 3 do i use to change email label globally?(signup, checkout, profile etc.) I'm not sure